# Create a new column from matched element between different columns containing arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, for-loop

I have a data frame where the the rows of the column col2 contains lists of numbers

```
    col1   col2

1 . 54319    54319, 54317
2 . 54317    37604, 37603, 37605
3 . 37603    123
4 . 37604    124
5 . 37605    1255
```

I would like to find matches between col1 and col2 and create a new column 'new' appending the groups in the col2 containing matches with col1

Result

```
    col1   col2                    new

1 . 54319    54319, 54317          54319, 54317
2 . 54317    37604, 37603, 37605   54319, 54317
3 . 37603    123                   37604, 37603, 37605
4 . 37604    124                   37604, 37603, 37605
5 . 37605    1255                  37604, 37603, 37605
```

This is my code, but it crashes. I guess I cannot read the lists contained in the rows of col2[rows]

```
new = []
for val in col1:
    for i in col2:
        if val in i:
           new.append(i)
        else:
           continue
```

print(new)

Answer (score 1):

Idea is ltest if match `col1` value in `col2` and for general solution return default value, here `no match` if value not exist:

```
f = lambda x: next(iter([y for y in df['col2'].tolist() if str(x) in y]), 'no match')
df['new'] = df['col1'].apply(f)
print (df)
   col1                 col2                  new
1   123       123, 562, 7779       123, 562, 7779
2   456        456, 111, 123        456, 111, 123
3   789       667, 1213, 456  1011, 444, 909, 789
4  1011  1213, 445, 909, 123  1011, 444, 909, 789
5  1213  1011, 444, 909, 789       667, 1213, 456
```

Also same working for list of values:

```
df['new'] = df['col1'].apply(f)
print (df)
   col1                   col2                    new
1   123       [123, 562, 7779]       [123, 562, 7779]
2   456        [456, 111, 123]        [456, 111, 123]
3   789       [667, 1213, 456]  [1011, 444, 909, 789]
4  1011  [1213, 445, 909, 123]  [1011, 444, 909, 789]
5  1213  [1011, 444, 909, 789]       [667, 1213, 456]
```

EDIT:

Last solution with `split` with `,`:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.split(', ')
f = lambda x: next(iter([y for y in df['col2'].tolist() if str(x) in y]), 'no match')
df['new'] = df['col1'].apply(f)
print (df)
    col1                   col2                    new
1  54319         [54319, 54317]         [54319, 54317]
2  54317  [37604, 37603, 37605]         [54319, 54317]
3  37603                  [123]  [37604, 37603, 37605]
4  37604                  [124]  [37604, 37603, 37605]
5  37605                 [1255]  [37604, 37603, 37605]
```

Comment: Hi have it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could I ask about what is the next() in the lambda function?

Comment: @Annalix - sure, it is trick for get first value, if empty list. Try `a = []` and `print (a[0])` failed, because not value. `a = [8,7,5]` and `print (a[0])` working.

Comment: If use `a = next(iter(a), '')` wotking for both lists - empty and not empty.

Comment: Thanks, all clear. One more question. If col2 contains NaN, does it still work? I have a .  AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'

Comment: @Annalix - no, solution should be changed. But first, there are lists like second paragrapg or strings like first?

Comment: Like first, so tolist() is necessary

Comment: @Annalix - Can you check this `f = lambda x: next(iter([y for y in df['col2'].dropna().tolist() if str(x) in y]), 'no match')` ?

Comment: Hi! Please, if I have list like the second case, [123, 562, 7779] but with none or NaN, does it fixed with a dropna(), or I should need to do some other change?

Comment: @Annalix are data confidental?

Comment: Yes, they are confidential

Comment: @Annalix - Still error? It is data related problem, not easy find it without real data

Comment: Ok, no problem. I am asking because in the previous comment you asked me which type list I had. No problem. I will try to figure out and in case I will tell you.Thanks . a lot!

Comment: @Annalix - yop, ony way is filter first 1000 rows, check solution, if fail, check first 500rows, and similar for find problematic data, then please add them to question and let me now for check solution. thanks

Comment: I  have another issue, if col2 I have 12, I will have the wrong result that it will be associated to the [123, 562, 7779]. Like I have just updated in your unswear

Comment: @Annalix - yop, then is necessary use second answer.

Comment: Thanks, but mine is not a list. How can I convert each group to a list?

Comment: @Annalix - Use `df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.split(',')`

Comment: It works correctly by adding a space in the split function otherwise will appear a space in the list that make element in the list non recognisable like ['123',' 562',' 7779']. It works adding a space in the split() function like df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.split(', ') to have the correct recognisable list as ['123','562','7779']

Comment: @Annalix - so sorry, you got it. Super. Added to answer this solution too.